# JavaScript: BufferLoader... loader.onload is not a function

Tags: javascript

So, I am working with this class BufferLoader and I am getting an error that says:

Uncaught TypeError: loader.onload is not a function:

Any ideas how to fix this but keep the code operating the same?

```
function BufferLoader(context, urlList, callback) {
  this.context = context;
  this.urlList = urlList;
  this.onload = callback;
  this.bufferList = new Array();
  this.loadCount = 0;
}

BufferLoader.prototype.loadBuffer = function(url, index) {
  // Load buffer asynchronously
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("GET", url, true);
  request.responseType = "arraybuffer";

  var loader = this;

  request.onload = function() {
    // Asynchronously decode the audio file data in request.response
    loader.context.decodeAudioData(
      request.response,
      function(buffer) {
        if (!buffer) {
          alert('error decoding file data: ' + url);
          return;
        }
        loader.bufferList[index] = buffer;
        if (++loader.loadCount == loader.urlList.length)
          loader.onload(loader.bufferList); // <<<****************************** here
      },
      function(error) {
        console.error('decodeAudioData error', error);
      }
    );
  }

  request.onerror = function() {
    alert('BufferLoader: XHR error');
  }

  request.send();
}

BufferLoader.prototype.load = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.urlList.length; ++i)
  this.loadBuffer(this.urlList[i], i);
}
```

This is how I am calling the class, now I am going to add filler text to show more text and now this is it:

```
  try { context = new AudioContext(); }
  catch(e) { alert("Web Audio API is not supported.") }

  beatsPerMinute = 120;

  bufferLoader = new BufferLoader(
    context,
    [
      "bass/dual_bass_1.wav",
      "bass/fusion_bass_c3.wav",
      "bass/fusion_accoustic_bass_c2.wav",
      "bass/casio_mt_45_bass_c2.wav",
      "bass/casio_cz_5000_synth_bass_c1.wav",
      "bass/bowed_bass_c2.wav",
      "bass/sanctuary_qcard_accoustic_bass_c2.wav"
    ]
    // finishedLoading
  );

  bufferLoader.load();
});
```

Comment: how are you using `BufferLoader`? are you creating a new instance of it? i.e. `new BufferLoader(context, urlList, callback)`

Comment: Well if someone passed no `callback` to your constructor then `.onload` won't be a function.

Comment: Updated to show how the class was being called...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no callback function assigned when you create a new BufferLoader, so onload will be undefined.

In order to fix you'll have to do:

```
try { context = new AudioContext(); }
catch(e) { alert("Web Audio API is not supported.") }

beatsPerMinute = 120;

bufferLoader = new BufferLoader(
  context,
  [
    "bass/dual_bass_1.wav",
    "bass/fusion_bass_c3.wav",
    "bass/fusion_accoustic_bass_c2.wav",
    "bass/casio_mt_45_bass_c2.wav",
    "bass/casio_cz_5000_synth_bass_c1.wav",
    "bass/bowed_bass_c2.wav",
    "bass/sanctuary_qcard_accoustic_bass_c2.wav"
  ],
  function(bufferList) {
    // Do stuff...
  }
);

bufferLoader.load();
});
```

Comment: Okay, I will test that!